# Unable to set my React component/jsx to have a dynamic table width

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to set a table in one my React components so that it has a dynamic table width.  However, I always get this error when I try and do it:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (37:50)

  35 |                     </tr>
  36 |                     <tr>
> 37 |                         <td style={{ width: 100% }}>
```

It works when I have a plain number, like 100 or 500, but not using percentages.

Is there a way for React/JSX to render dynamic tables?

thanks!

Comment: width : "100%" will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `<td style={{ width: "100%" }}>` or `<td style={{ width: 100 + "%" }}>`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because React/JSX doesn't recognize what you mean by width: 100%. Put 100% in quotes and your error should go away.

```js
 <td style={{ width: "100%" }}>
```